# How to display image into each recent post in drupal front page?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I am very new to drupal. As I have seen many of drupal free theme can show image in the recent post on the first page of drupal

I tried searching some ways to do but seem my keyword search was mismatched.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to install any modules, you can simply use a standard HTML `<img>` tag to put an image in your node body (make sure your selected *Input Format* allows for the use of that tag). You can then use FTP to upload the linked images to your /sites/default/files directory.

The modules mentioned by Nikit (especially IMCE) can ease this process greatly. A the very minimum, IMCE allows you to upload files to your server without using FTP and adds a handy "insert image" link after your "body" input fields. Clicking that link uploads your image and then generates the `<img>` code for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply style it in node body (wysiwyg + imce can help to quickly upload image and style it).

But recommend to you use image or cck + imagefield, and theme it via node-{CONTENTTYPE}.tpl.php
Little help here: http://www.hankpalan.com/blog/drupal-themes/theming-node-drupalthe-easy-way

But recommend to learn theming in drupal.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use HTML or change any PHP files then use the admin console.

http://drupal.org/node/1047760